Can not iterate "cbar" or "cmins" in multiple violinplot in a single plot
I am trying to change colors of each violinplot in multiple plots in a single plot. I can change colors of the bodies, but I can not change the colors for cbars, cmins, cmaxes. How do I do this?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mock_data= [
           [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
           [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
           [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
           [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
           [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
           [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
           [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
           [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
           [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17],
           [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
           ]
pos      = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
colors   = ["C0","C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9"]
fig, ax  = plt.subplots(1,1)

violin   = ax.violinplot(mock_data,positions=pos)

for things in ["bodies","cbars","cmins","cmaxes"]:
   for vp, co in zip(violin[things],colors):
      vp.set_facecolor(co)
      vp.set_edgecolor(co)


plt.show()

With above code, I get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/downloads/violin.py", line 25, in <module>
    for vp, co in zip(violin[things],colors):
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'LineCollection' object is not iterable


It seems that only violin["bodies"]is iteratable, but violin["cbars"],violin["cmins"],violin["cmaxes"] are not. Given this, how do I efficiently change the lines colors of means, mins and maxes?

That's normal since only the "bodies" are iterable, as you've already noticed.
{
    'bodies': [
        <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x15fd0781df0>,
        ...
        <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x15fd0a3fa70>
    ],
    'cmaxes': <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x15fd071f710>,
    'cmins':  <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x15fd0a68d10>,
    'cbars':  <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x15fd0781430>
}

One possible fix is to handle each component separately :
for comp, coll in violin.items():
    if comp == "bodies":
        for pc, co in zip(coll, colors):
            pc.set_facecolor(co)
            pc.set_edgecolor(co)
    else:
        coll.set_color(colors)



It works! Thank you!
